# Integrating splines over a set of cells

Tags: r, spatial, splines, numerical-integration

Let $f(s) = \sum_{i=1}^p \beta_i \phi_i(s)$ such that $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto  \mathbb{R}_+$ and the $\phi_i$ are splines (B-splines or Thin-plate splines) and suppose we are interested in $W\subset  \mathbb{R}^2$ and we have a fixed partition of $W$, $\{C_j\}_{j=1}^m$. I'd like to find the coefficients
$$
\int_{C_j} f(s) ds =  \int_{C_j}\sum_{i=1}^p \beta_i \phi_i(s)ds = \sum_{i=1}^p \beta_i  \int_{C_j}\phi_i(s)ds = \sum_{i=1}^p \beta_i  \Phi_{ij} 
$$
I'd like to find the coefficients $\Phi_{ij}$.

The package using R and I know that the package $\texttt{splines2}$ provides a way to evaluate and integrate B-splines over a set of points, however I don't see how to do the above integration over cells $C_j$.

Should I do Monte Carlo integration instead? I could sample points inside the cell and take the mean weighted by the distribution used to simulate points, for example.

-- EDIT --

Sample code from the package $\texttt{splines2}$ for integrals of splines:

```
library(splines2)
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(10)
knots <- c(0.3, 0.5, 0.6) # internal knots

## cubic B-splines
bsMat <- bSpline(x, knots = knots, degree = 3, intercept = TRUE)
ibsMat <- update(bsMat, integral = TRUE) # the integrals
```